# .htaccess display /base1/folder/ using the content of /base2/folder.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I open the url `http://mysite.com/base1/folder/`, I want it to display the contents of `http://mysite.com/base2/folder.html`.  There is an index.html file in the folder `folder`.

To be clearer, the html file `folder.html` resides in the folder `base2`.

My .htaccess file does not work as expected

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/base1/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /base2/$1.html [L]
```

Could anyone please tell me is wrong with my .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression looks wrong:

```
^/base1/([^/]+)/(.+)$
                 ^^^ requires one or more characters
```

This should work (to accept *anything* following /folder/)

```
^/base1/([^/]+)/
```

Or this (to accept only /folder/)

```
^/base1/([^/]+)/$
```

Furthermore I would remove the two `RewriteCond` as your rule. (Though they shouldn't do any harm if /base1/ doesn't exist)

Comment: I have tried both `^/base1/([^/]+)/` and `^/base1/([^/]+)/$` and removed the 2 `RewriteCond`but it still does not work. The content of `base2/$1.html` is not displayed.

Comment: hm, I would enable logging: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel maybe that brings something up

Comment: Hi Niko, I'm sorry that was actually my mistake. The browser cached the pages so i did not test it correctly. Now it works fine :-)